# Flutter: App keeps going back to initial route after hot reload

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have just upgraded FireBase plugins to latest version as per migration guide https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration and started noticing that whenever I do hot reload my app is doing hot restart and goes back to initial route. First I thought It may be Android Studio issue so I tried through command prompt and VS code too, but same result. I have search through older Stackoverflow questions related to the topic but couldn't find anything that would fix the problem.
I am copying my code below.
PS: I am pretty new to Flutter and it is my first ever question in stackoverflow.

Really appreciate any help.
EDIT: Just debugged it and found that It goes back to runApp(...) when hot reload is performed.

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  String authMethod;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferenceService localStorage = SharedPreferenceService();
  authMethod = await localStorage.getAuthMode();
  print("Authentication Mode $authMethod");
  setupLocator();


  runApp(
    DevicePreview(
        enabled: false,//kReleaseMode,
        builder: (context)=>AppInitialization())
      );
}
```

AppInitialization.dart

```
class AppInitialization extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Unable to Initialize FireBase'),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          print("======= F I R E  B A S E  A P P ========");
          return LocalGroceryOnline();
        }
        return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.redAccent, )),
          ),
        );

        });
  }
}
```

LocalGroceryOnline.dart

```
class LocalGroceryOnline extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return MultiProvider  (
      providers: [
        Provider<FirebaseAuthService>(create: (_) => FirebaseAuthService()),
        Provider<SignInHelperService>(create: (_) => SignInHelperService()),
        Provider<SharedPreferenceService>(create: (_) => SharedPreferenceService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CartModel>(create: (_) => CartModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserModel>(create: (_) => UserModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductModel>(create: (_) => ProductModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<cat.Category>(create: (_) => cat.Category()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AppSetting>(create: (_) => AppSetting()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<bool>>(create: (_) => ValueNotifier<bool>(false),),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<int>>(create: (_) => ValueNotifier<int>(0),)

      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Online Local Grocery',
        locale: DevicePreview.of(context).locale,
        builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(elevation: 0.0), //This is important

        ),
        initialRoute: AuthWidget.id,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,

        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        //onGenerateInitialRoutes: InitialRouteGenerator.generateRoute(),
      )
          ,
    );
  }
}
```

RouteGenerator.dart

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case AuthWidget.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AuthWidget());

      case SignUpSelectionScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpSelectionScreen());
      case SignupForm.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignupForm());
      case LoginView.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginView());
      case HomePage.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
      case MainPage.id:
        if (args.runtimeType == MainCategory) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => MainPage(
                mainCategory: args,
              ));
        }
        return _errorRoute();
      case ProductDetail.id:
        if (args.runtimeType == SelectedProductArguments) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => ProductDetail(
                    selectedProductArguments: args,
                  ));
        }
        return _errorRoute();
      case CheckOutScreen.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CheckOutScreen());
      case Admin.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Admin());
      case ScrapBoard.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ScrapBoard());
      case ProductAdminView.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ProductAdminView());
      case DeliveryAddressView.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DeliveryAddressView());
      case PaymentView.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PaymentView());
      case OrderProcessingView.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => OrderProcessingView());
      case MyOrdersView.id:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyOrdersView());
      case MyOrderDetails.id:
        if (args.runtimeType == Order) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyOrderDetails(
          order: args,
        )
         );
        }
        return _errorRoute();

      default:
        // If there is no such named route in the switch statement, e.g. /third
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Error'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('ERROR'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class InitialRouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    bool _firstTimeAppUsed;
    final localStorage = new SharedPreferenceService();
    localStorage.isFirstTimeAppUsed().then((bool value) {
      if (value == true) {
        _firstTimeAppUsed = true;
      }
    });
    if (_firstTimeAppUsed) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignUpSelectionScreen());
    }
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage());
  }
}
```

AuthWidget.dart

```
class AuthWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = "auth_widget";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Auth Widget...");
    final authService =
        Provider.of<FirebaseAuthService>(context, listen: false);
    final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context, listen: false);
    final signInHelperService = Provider.of<SignInHelperService>(context, listen: false);

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: authService.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            print ("INSIDE AUTH WIDGET");
            final user = snapshot.data;
            if (user != null) {
              print("${user.uid} ${user.userName} ${user.photoUrl}");
              userModel.user = user;
              return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(user.uid)
                      .get().asStream(),
                  builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
                    if (userSnapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                      final userDocument = userSnapshot.data;
                      if (userDocument != null) {
                        print("------ Data Found -------");
                        AppUser user = AppUser.fromMap(userDocument);
                        //bool signUpComplete = userDocument["signUpComplete"];
                        bool signUpComplete = user.signUpComplete;
                        if (signUpComplete == null) signUpComplete = false;
                        if (!signUpComplete) {
                          print("userModel.user UID ${userModel.user.uid}");
                          return SignupForm();
                        } else {
                          AppUser user2 = AppUser.fromMap(userDocument);
                          userModel.user = user2;
                          print('User Level ..... ${userModel.user.userLevel}');
                          signInHelperService.getAndUpdateDeviceToken(user2);

                          return HomePage(); //MainPage();
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    return emptyScaffoldWithProgress();
                  });
            }
            return SignUpSelectionScreen();
          }
          return emptyScaffoldWithProgress();
        });
  }

  Scaffold emptyScaffoldWithProgress() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 90,
          width: 90,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 5.0,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.redAccent)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (3 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Jamal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Jamal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.17.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Found culprit, it was DevicePreview which cause to execute runApp on hot reload. I don't  know why now as it was working fine. I have removed it now. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Faced same problem on using onGenerateRoute on Flutter 3.3.0, but without any thing like mentioned above.
Solved by adding home on MaterialApp

Comment: Same. Though I don't want to add `home`. `onGenerateRoute` is a better place to have the logic that decides `home`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit, it was `DevicePreview` which cause to execute `runApp` on hot reload. I don't know why now as it was working fine. I have removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code you are calling **LocalGroceryOnline()** inside a **FutureBuilder**  and that FutureBuilder you are calling inside runApp() functions so when you try to hot reload or browser refresh it has to go through that futurebuilder and because of that routes you provided does not get injected into memory and broswer will redirect to initial route with error saying : `could not navigate to initial route`.
You should have an **MaterialApp** or **GetMaterialApp** inside runApp() as root, do not wrap MaterialApp with futurebuilder or any async function this can create issue with flutter routing.

Tip : If you are someone wrapping your MaterialApp with some third party plugin's builder/widget for any of these tasks like :routing middleware, internet connectivity listener, flavour, responsive framework, screenutil, authservice etc make sure that widget/builder functions is not a futurebuilder or async task otherwise it will mess up with your routing. Hope it helps, Happy Coding!